# SSIS Package should fail for invalid parameter values

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have to implement a scenario in SSIS, if the SSIS package receives invalid parameter value like passing `-65` to `int` parameter then package should fail.

But in my case it is not failing instead it is getting executed with success message without data.

Comment: too less information about your problem

Comment: -65 is a valid int?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate parameters using expression in your control flow:
[image]

If the value is -65 then cast from "Invalid parameter exception" to int will throw exception. Then the package will fail.